# Vector analysis:Finding components after rotation

Tags: vector-analysis

> A vector $\vec{a}$ has components $2p$ and $1$ with respect to a
>   rectangular Cartesian system. This system is rotated through a certain
>   angle about the origin in the counterclockwise sense. If, with respect
>   to the new system, $\vec{a}$ has components $p + 1$ and $1$, then how
>   to find the value of $p$ from this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Length is preserved by rotations.